# Flot chart x axis time is displaying wrong details in the starting of xaxis

Tags: charts, flot

I am facing an issue with flotchart x-axis time issue. XAxis data is displaying the wrong details.

Here in the Datagrid time is started from 13:00:04, but in the chart, time is starting from 8:00`.9:00,10:00:11:00:12:00 as you can see in the above screenshot. Actually, it should start from 13:00, I am not sure why 8:00, 9:00 ...12:00 are coming in the chart x-axis. Can anyone please help me? Thanks
[image]

Below is the code snippet.
[image]

Comment: Probably timezone issues, make sure that data and axis ticks are both UTC or both local time.

Comment: Hi Raidri, After setting the **timezone: 'browser'** then it worked. thanks